# Typeclass instances with constrained return type

Tags: haskell, overloading, type-families, associated-types

I'm implementing a notion of inner product that's general over the container and numerical types. The definition states that the return type of this operation is a (non-negative) real number.
One option (shown below) is to write all instances by hand, for each numerical type (Float, Double, Complex Float, Complex Double, Complex CFloat, Complex CDouble, etc.). The primitive types aren't many, but I dislike the repetition.
Another option, or so I thought, is to have a parametric instance with a constraint such as `RealFloat` (which represents `Float` and `Double`).

```
{-# language MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}
module Test where

import Data.Complex

class Hilbert c e where
  type HT e :: *
  dot :: c e -> c e -> HT e


instance Hilbert [] Double where
  type HT Double = Double
  dot x y = sum $ zipWith (*) x y

instance Hilbert [] (Complex Double) where
  type HT (Complex Double) = Double
  a `dot` b = realPart $ sum $ zipWith (*) (conjugate <$> a) b
```

### Question

Why does the instance below not work ("Couldn't match type `e` with `Double`.. expected type `HT e`, actual type `e`")?

```
instance RealFloat e => Hilbert [] e where
  type HT e = Double
  dot x y = sum $ zipWith (*) x y
```

Comment: `sum` returns an `e` (since `x` and `y` have type `[e]`) but `dot` should be returning a `HT e = Double`. Somehow, you'll need to convert `e` to a `Double`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that particular instance doesn't work because the `sum` only yields an `e`, but you want the result to be `Double`. As `e` *is* constrained to `RealFrac`, this is easy to fix though, as any `Real` (questionable though is is mathematically) can be converted to a `Fractional`:

```
  dot x y = realToFrac . sum $ zipWith (*) x y
```

However, that generic instance prevents you from also defining complex instances: with `instance RealFloat e => Hilbert [] e where` you cover *all* types, even if they aren't really real numbers. You could still instantiate `Complex` as an overlapping instance, but I'd rather stay away from those if I could help it.

It's also questionable if such vectorspace classes should be defined on `* -> *` at all. Yes, [`linear`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear) also does it this way, but IMO parametricity doesn't work in our favour in this application. Have you checked out the [`vector-space` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space)? Mind, it isn't exactly complete for doing serious linear algebra; that's a gap I hope to fill with my [`linearmap-category` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category/docs/Math-LinearMap-Category.html).

Comment: Interesting. Can you elaborate on what's wrong with `linear` and parametricity? I just quickly looked at it, and can't spot the issue you hint at.

Comment: @chi: the most practical problem is that it prevents you from using unboxed vector types, which really is a big issue for serious linear algebra. On a more mathematical level: a vector space should be basis-agnostic – it's something abstract geometric, and any array-of-numbers representation just arises from an arbitrary choice of basis, which should not influence any end results. But if you fmap a nonlinear operation over a `*->*` vector, you'll get a different result depending on which basis the representation refers to.

Comment: @leftaroundabout thank you for your input; could you suggest an improvement for the class design? E.g. how to solve the overlapping instances problem. On the other hand, I need the "container" idea (`* -> *`) to make certain optimizations possible (sparse computations).

Comment: @ocramz there is no overlapping instances problem if you define the instances individually, which is what I'd suggest. (Of course that's not to encourage code duplication in general, but for class instances like this it's generally very little code, or else you can define all instances in terms of just two different helper functions.)

Comment: It eludes me why you think a `*->*` type would give you any edge in sparse optimisation. Any `*->*` structure can also be used in a `*` class be applying it to an arbitrary particular type; OTOH if you need to support full parametricity you can't make the sparseness dependent on the contained values.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I understood my error with `* -> *` by studying more closely `vector-space`. Can you expand on your last remark? " if you need to support full parametricity you can't make the sparseness dependent on the contained values"

Comment: @ocramz: example — if your sparse structure is, say, `Map Int Double`, you can eliminate zeroes created in a vector addition by cancelling. That's not possible if the addition operation has the signature `(^+^) :: Num a => f a -> f a -> f a`, because you can't zero-check those general-number elements. Ok, now you say you could just add an `Eq` constraint. But in practice that wouldn't be much use because floating-point addition makes it rather unlikely to obtain exact zeroes. You'd need some sort of uncertainty handling. This gets very fiddly if you don't have access to the concrete type.